# Deserialize object to PC File System and use as resource?

Tags: java, android, serialization, file-io, resources

This may be a silly question:

I'm looking to serialize an object as a once-off to then use that thereafter as a resource (deserializing each time it's read).  How can I write this serialized object once so I can access it from the PC and put it in the `/res/raw` folder (where it will then always just be read in and deserialized)?

I've tried:

```
                 try
                 {
                   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/solver.sol"));
                   ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                   out.writeObject(solver);
                   out.close();
                 }
                 catch(IOException ex)
                 {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

Aswell as placing `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in the AndroidManifest.xml
But I can't access it from my PC to place it in the resources folder?

Thanks in Advance

Calum

Comment: Why can't you access this file? Can you access other files on the SD card?

Comment: You show that you have tried to do it a certain way: what is wrong with that way? At first glance, that appears to be what you want. What's not working about it? What are the symptoms?

Comment: @Pixie Yeah, I can access all the other files/directories on the SD card root.  I thought I could just write to the root of the SD card, then go fetch it in Windows, but the file is nowhere to be seen... I'm getting no errors/exceptions thrown.  Thought I might have missed some fact about the filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

...instead of `.toString()`

Comment: Thanks MisterSquonk, this helped.  What you said and the fact that I needed to disconnect the USB cable from the PC whilst I was debugging solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

@MisterSquonk is right. Also, try closing the `FileOutputStream` before unmounting the SD card.